# How to bind several data frames obtained from web scraping, using a for loop?

Tags: r

So I have vector that is basically a list of species such as:

```
list_species<-c("Pomphorhynchus laevis","Profilicollis altmani","Leptorhynchoides thecatus","Mayarhynchus karlae","Oligacanthorhynchus tortuosa","Pseudoacanthocephalus toshimai","Corynosoma australe")
```

And I have this function, which mines data on several specimens for each of those species:

```
library(bold)
df<-bold_seqspec(name_of_species, format = "tsv")
```

I want to use the bold_seqspec function to create one data frame for each of the elements in list_species, so far I tried like this:

```
for (name_of_species in list_species){
  df<-bold_seqspec(name_of_species, format = "tsv")
  joined_dfs<-rbind(df)
}
```

What I wanted was a data frame that is the sum of all the data frames which were downloaded for in species name in list_species.
But what I'm getting is a data frame with one observation one, so something must be wrong in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```r
do.call(rbind, lapply(list_species, bold_seqspec, format = "tsv"))
```

Explanation: `lapply(list_species, bold_seqspec, format = "tsv")` loops through `list_species` and applies `bold_seqspec` to every element with argument `format = "tsv"`. The return object is a `list` of `bold_seqspec` return objects; assuming they are `data.frame`s you can then row-bind them with `do.call(rbind, ...)`, producing a single `data.frame`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to apply this for multiple species, you need to loop over them.

You can use `purrr`'s `map` functions.

```
joined_dfs <- purrr::map_df(list_species, bold::bold_seqspec)
```